# how to retrive data from user account having administrator power?

Tags: windows-xp, passwords, data-recovery, user-accounts, password-recovery

I installed Windows XP on my system and made two user accounts which one has administrator power and the other is just a normal user.  After that I didn't use the system for more than month.  During that time I forgot the password for the admin user account and I could not access the account.

I have some very important projects and documents in that account.  I can see that account from system administrator default account but can't open or access it. I want to retrieve all the data from that account.

How can I retrieve the data or retrieve the password?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve your admin account from your normal( standard ) account .
But you can try this,

- While booting your PC , press f5 or f10 etc ., to enter safe mode
- After that you will see another Administrator account in the top of the user list with your existing account.
- Now click that account it won't prompt you for password
- Now you can reset or change your old admin account password or get your files back now.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I hope your suggestion help me to accessing my account.

Comment: I tried to safe mode but not got the solution

Answer (score 0):

If recovering the password does not work. Burn a [LIVE linux cd](http://livecdlist.com/), boot the computer into it and then mount the hard drive and transfer the data.

Or use [Kon-Boot](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/).
Kon Boot silently bypass's the authentication process of Windows based operating systems (both 32-bit and 64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Use Trinity rescue kit, it's a Linux live cd it has a program called winpass that will reset the password for you, there are full instructions here http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?wpid=42&front_id=12